Designing an oscillator circuit in Cadence Virtuoso, but not sure why the comparator portion is not working
I am currently in the process of designing and testing an oscillator design which consists of a current reference and a comparator based on common gate topology (right hand side circled in red.)

The circuit it currently biased in sub-threshold saturation as per power requirements,  I am currently stuck in debugging the common gate comparator stage.
When the CG_IN is > Vref, I expect the transistor NM2 to turn OFF, hence pulling CG_OUT to VDD (minus small Vds of PM2), thus causing the switch NM3 to discharge the capacitor.
When CG_IN < Vref, I expect NM2 to be ON and hence allow the capacitor to charge, thereby acting like a comparator.
What I notice is as seen in the screenshot below: As CG_IN < Vref, I expect CG_OUT to be pulled to close to VDD, but I don't see this happening.

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to debug this kind of circuit?
Reference circuit for CG based comparator from aN IEEE paper:


Can you edit your top two images to have a white background please.

Your negative terminal of E0 is floating. That E0 sourc amplifies the difference between its terminals, but this difference is not defined because your (-) is floating.

I believe the negative terminal E0 floating is perfectly okay, since its just acting like an amplifier for the input voltage at +ve terminal, given the negative is GND or Floating

not its not OK to have floating. connect it to GND

I think you missed the whole point of the clock buffer in the source circuit. It sets the absolute voltage threshold function that triggers the reset/discharge transistor NM3. The clock buffer will provide some hysteresis between charging and discharging of the capacitor by providing a time delay. Your VCVS will do neither if those functions. All that will happen is that the circuit will find a DC equilibrium state.
Additionally, I'm not sure your negative terminal of the VCVS input is connected to anything.
You need that clock buffer block in the schematic. At the end of the day, it's a digital CMOS buffer. You might need multiple stages to get a cleaner signal, but there's a lot of tunable parameters in that circuit as well.
Right now, the VCVS is turning the reset/discharge transistor on hard (Vgs NM3 = 85mV). Normally, if CG_OUT was going to a digital buffer, you would need to get to about mid-rail (e.g. 35-45mV) before it would start to change from a saturated 0mV output (logic 0) to the saturated 85mV output (logic 1). However, since you used a VCVS with a gain of 10, CG_OUT only can get to 8.5mV before VGS NM3 is "pegged" at 85mV.
Normally, Vs of NM2 would need to rise above VREF (5.7mV) to start to turn off NM2, but it can't rise when NM3 is on. I still strongly believe that adding the digital buffer will be the easiest solution, but you might be able to get a bit further by reducing the VCVS gain  to maybe 2-3?
You might check your PFET bias voltages, as you're driving them hard relative to your NFETs. I'm not sure if that's intentional or not and I don't do much subthreshold. (If VDD > 2*Vt, they'd be out of saturation)
Finally, build a version of your circuit where you break the feedback loop. This will let you run a DC sweep and actually analyze what the switching thresholds for the circuit are. I can't run the simulation here and I'm not going to guess at models, but here's the idea for a testbench:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

I see what you mean, but im certain the clock buffer is not the voltage comparator.
The comparator here is designed using a Common Gate stage with a capacitor and switch to discharge it.
Hope this clarifies the question better.

It is an additional switching voltage comparison that will have its own switching point. I understand how this circuit should work, and why your implementation doesn't... I'm just having a hard time explaining without waving hands in front of a white board.

your circuit won't work in general if the clock buffer doesn't have some delay -- the circuit will regulate the capacitor and other voltages to just balance.
Having some delay (or hysteresis) in the clock buffer will likely allow the circuit to work. You can think of the delay as what gives the C time to get discharged.
In addition, in SPICE, the circuit may simulate as stable and not oscillating. You need to use initial conditions, or just ramp the power supply from 0.
